# SELECT doesn't display column names

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

When I don't use the SET command, I get results like:

```
SQL> select * from <tablename>;

         NAME          PLACE        AGE         GENDER        DESTINATION
    -------------- -------------- ---------   ------------  ---------------
          Joy         Scotland      22           Male          California
```

When I use the SET variable :

```
SET LIN 32000 pagesize 0

SQL> select * from <tablename>;
```

I get the results in better format but not too good:

```
 Joy Scotland                                     22 Male                                                                             California
```

1. How can I display the output in better way (e.g. columns are separated with a delimiter (space))
2. When we use SET, why did the column headers disappear? How can I improve it?

Comment: 1.) What DBMS are we talking about? 2.) What client?

Comment: What software are you talking about? 'SET LIN'?? Please edit your question, and show your SQL statement.

Comment: This is not SQL, this is some Oracle specialization, tag your question accordingly so I can ignore it http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2678481.

Comment: @Jodrell : I used the same documentation for my formatting of the display.

Comment: @piet.t : it is a server application. it is Oracle DB.

Comment: @JanDoggen : I have EDITED my post. I am using SELECT, and all I want to see the results in a better format. I am nt using any application (like TOAD etc.), I am doing it on command line with 'sqlplus'.

Comment: @ErAB Please take a moment to learn how to format properly in SO :)

Comment: try by changing the pagesize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**SET PAGES[IZE] {14 | n}**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699247)
>
> Sets the number of rows on each page of output in iSQL*Plus, and the
>   number of lines on each page of output in command-line and Windows
>   GUI. **You can set PAGESIZE to zero to suppress all headings**, page
>   breaks, titles, the initial blank line, and other formatting
>   information.

You set the pagesize as 0, that's why you are not getting the heading. Try 1 or the default 14.

```
SET LIN 32000 pagesize 1
- OR -
SET LIN 32000 PAGES 1
```

**Btw, this is not SQL.** It's a bunch of Oracle commands used to control the database behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The following links provide good information about formatting output results in Oracle SQL Plus.

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/beautify.html
http://larig.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/formatting-oracle-output-in-sqlplus/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To export data to csv-file via sqlplus I use a script like

```
set colsep ";"    -- column separator
set pagesize 0    -- no column headings
set feedback off  -- no "xx rows selected"
set trimspool on  -- no line-padding
set linesize 9999 -- length of output line
set verify off    -- no output of parameter replacements
set termout off   -- no console output
spool export.csv  -- redirect output to file
select * from mytable;
spool off         -- stop output to file
```

If you omit the `set pagesize 0` you'll get column headers, but shortened to field length and repeated every `(pagesize-3)` lines.